# Error when trying to make relation in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make a relationship in Laravel but always get the error:

> Trying to get property 'nama_guru' of non-object (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\supervisi_digital\resources\views\ManagementSupervisi\index.blade.php).

Here is my code:

**Dokumen Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Dokumen extends Model
{
    protected $table = "dokumen";
    protected $primarikey = "id";
    protected $fillable =
    [
        'id', 'nama_guru', 'mapel', 'file', 'keterangan'
    ];

    public function supervisi()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Supervisi::class);
    }
}
```

**Supervisi Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class Supervisi extends Model
    {
        protected $table = "supervisi";
        protected $primarikey = "id";
        protected $fillable =
        [
            'id', 'id_guru', 'id_mapel', 'id_keterangan', 'penilaian'
        ];
    
        public function dokumen()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(Dokumen::class);
        }
    }
```

**Blade View**

```
<table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>NAMA GURU</th>
            <th>MAPEL</th>
            <th>KETERANGAN</th>
            <th>PENILAIAN</th>
            <th>ACTION</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($dtSupervisi as $item)
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
            <td>{{ $item->dokumen->nama_guru }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            </td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

**Controller**
public function index()
{
$dtSupervisi = Supervisi::with('dokumen')->paginate(10);
return view('ManagementSupervisi.index', compact('dtSupervisi'));
}

I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Does Supervisi have a `dokumen_id`? If not, then you cannot use the BelongsTo relationship like that.

Comment: You forget add foreign/local keys to relationships. https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: thanks bro, i add foreign key/local keys and it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the foreign key and local key in your relationship.

```
public function dokumen()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Dokumen::class,'foreign_key','localkey');
}
```

so

```
public function dokumen()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Dokumen::class,'id_guru','id');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
protected $fillable =
    [
        'id', 'id_guru', 'id_mapel', 'id_keterangan', 'penilaian', 'dokumen_id'
    ];
```

**Use dokumen_id in Supervisi model and supervisi table after migrate database may be it's work**